# Perl: How do I get "bytes read" from md5::digest addfile()?

Tags: perl, md5

I am using Digest::MD5 to compute MD5 of a data stream; namely a GZIPped file (or to be precise, 3000) that are much too large to fit in RAM. So I'm doing this:

```
 use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_base64);

 my ($filename) = @_;                # this is in a sub
 my $ctx = Digest::MD5 -> new;

 $openme = $filename;        # Usually, it's a plain file
 $openme = "gunzip -c '$filename' |" if ($filename =~ /\.gz$/); # is gz

 open (FILE, $openme); # gunzip to STDOUT
 binmode(FILE);
 $ctx -> addfile(*FILE);   # passing filehandle
 close(FILE);
```

This is a success.  `addfile` neatly slurps in the output of gunzip and gives a correct MD5.

**However, I would really, really like to know the size of the slurped data** (gunzipped "file" in this case).

I could add an additional

```
  $size = 0 + `gunzip -c very/big-file.gz | wc -c`;
```

but that would involve reading the file twice.

Is there any way to extract the number of bytes slurped from Digest::MD5? I tried capturing the result: `$result = $ctx -> addfile(*FILE);` and doing Data::Dumper on both $result and $ctx, but nothing interesting emerged.

Edit: The files are often not gzipped.  Added code to show what I really do.

Comment: Maybe use [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) to read the file a block at a time and compute the length of the data and its digest as you go, instead of relying on an external program?

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it all in perl, without relying on an external program for the decompression:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw/$GunzipError/;
use Digest::MD5;

my $filename = shift or die "Missing gzip filename!\n";

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
# Allow for reading both gzip format files and uncompressed files.
# This is the default behavior, but might as well be explicit about it.
my $z = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($filename, Transparent => 1)
  or die "Unable to open $filename: $GunzipError\n";
my $len = 0;

while ((my $blen = $z->read(my $block)) > 0) {
  $len += $blen;
  $md5->add($block);
}
die "There was an error reading the file: $GunzipError\n" unless $z->eof;

say "Total uncompressed length: $len";
say "MD5: ", $md5->hexdigest;
```

---

If you want to use `gunzip` instead of the core `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` module, you can do something similar, though, using `read` to get a chunk of data at a time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie; # So we don't have to explicitly check for i/o related errors
use feature qw/say/;
use Digest::MD5;

my $filename = shift or die "Missing gzip filename!\n";

my $md5 = Digest::MD5->new;
# Note use of lexical file handle and safer version of opening a pipe
# from a process that eliminates shell shenanigans. Also uses the :raw
# perlio layer instead of calling binmode on the handle (which has the
# same effect)
open my $z, "-|:raw", "gunzip", "-c", $filename;
# Non-compressed version
# open my $z, "<:raw", $filename;
my $len = 0;

while ((my $blen = read($z, my $block, 4096)) > 0) {
  $len += $blen;
  $md5->add($block);
}

say "Total uncompressed length: $len";
say "MD5: ", $md5->hexdigest;
```

Comment: Interesting.  Part of my problem is I can't rely on the file being gzip'd.  As it is now, the code is written to read plain files, and I have a simple shim:  `if /gz$/ { $filename = "gunzip -c $filename |" } stuck before the open.

Comment: @Harper The default behavior of the module is to, if the file isn't in gzip format, just pass it through unchanged (This can be explicitly set with the `Transparent` option to the constructor; let me update the code to show that.)

Comment: @Shawn That's really slick. *Hmm, wait*.  What does the module do with a file that *was supposed* to be a gzip file, but has file damage? I have some of those.

Comment: @Harper Also added some error reporting for if it encounters a problem while decompressing the file.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the contents yourself, and feed it in to `$ctx->add($data)`, and keep a running count of how much data you've passed through. Whether you add all the data in a single call, or across multiple calls, doesn't make any difference to the underlying algorithm. The docs include:

> ```
>     All these lines will have the same effect on the state of the $md5 object:
>
>         $md5->add("a"); $md5->add("b"); $md5->add("c");
>         $md5->add("a")->add("b")->add("c");
>         $md5->add("a", "b", "c");
>         $md5->add("abc");
> ```

which indicates that you can just do this a piece at a time.